# Controlling a rotary controller by a stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, rotary-encoder

I have seen a lot of projects showing how to control a stepper motor with a rotary controller.

Has anybody ever seen a solution for the inverse problem? I would like to control a rotary controller with a stepper motor, because I do not want to violate the integrity of an electrical gadget. Otherwise the permission to run the gadget is lost. I am living in Germany which is ruled by lots of permissions.

Comment: Realize that a stepper motor does not provide absolute position. If you need absolute position on your rotary controller, you need a separate position encoder.

Comment: The mechanical coupling can be tricky. Good news, because so many people are building DIY 3D printers, cheap couplings are available.

Comment: What is a rotary controller? Specifications please.

Comment: I've seen such a mechanical contraption implemented - to control a 100kV power supply. Problems arose because it was too slow, The VARIAC that the stepper drove constantly needed its brush replaced. It was a mess of a solution. After pointing out its limitations, permission was granted to do a proper electronic equivalent, which did work more reliably, and with improved performance. Perhaps I'm biased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly it's possible, but it's much more a mechanical problem than an electronic one.

It comes down to how you can mechanically connect to the knob you want to turn, and where you can mount your stepper motor or server.

If you can put a toothed pulley in place of your knob it might be a lot easier.
[image]

A servo might be easier than a stepper motor (because you have absolute position):
[image]

Here's a [project](https://www.candrian.gr/index.php/logitech-z623-remote-control-ir-wifi-hardware-hack/) for doing exactly what you wanted, except a) inside the equipment, and with some modifications to the potentiometer which is being turned.